How do I solve the "No such activation function: 'sum'" error in Python NEAT?
I was creating a simple game AI using NEAT. However, I discovered an issue where the game window would just open and close as it transitioned from generation 0 to generation 1, and in reality, it kept repeating generation 0, so I asked gpt to modify it. When I ran the modified code, I got the following message:
eunwoocho@Eunwoos-MacBook-Pro python % /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/eunwoocho/Documents/Python/import pygame.py"
pygame 2.5.2 (SDL 2.28.3, Python 3.12.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html

****** Running generation 0 ******

Population's average fitness: 4.55500 stdev: 8.71705
Best fitness: 68.00000 - size: (10, 36) - species 69 - id 69
Average adjusted fitness: 0.067
Mean genetic distance 3.545, standard deviation 0.244
Population of 402 members in 200 species:
ID age size fitness adj fit stag
==== === ==== ======= ======= ====
1 0 2 1.0 0.015 0
.....omit....
200 0 2 0.0 0.000 0
Total extinctions: 0
Generation time: 2.484 sec

****** Running generation 1 ******

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/eunwoocho/Documents/Python/import pygame.py", line 129, in <module>
run(config_path, 50)
File "/Users/eunwoocho/Documents/Python/import pygame.py", line 121, in run
winner = p.run(lambda genomes, config: main(genomes, config, p.generation, target_generations), target_generations)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/neat/population.py", line 89, in run
fitness_function(list(iteritems(self.population)), self.config)
File "/Users/eunwoocho/Documents/Python/import pygame.py", line 121, in <lambda>
winner = p.run(lambda genomes, config: main(genomes, config, p.generation, target_generations), target_generations)
File "/Users/eunwoocho/Documents/Python/import pygame.py", line 57, in main
net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(g, config)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/neat/nn/feed_forward.py", line 51, in create
activation_function = config.genome_config.activation_defs.get(ng.activation)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/neat/activations.py", line 128, in get
raise InvalidActivationFunction("No such activation function: {0!r}".format(name))
neat.activations.InvalidActivationFunction: No such activation function: 'sum'

The game did move from generation 0 to generation 1, but an error message
"No such activation function: 'sum'"

occurred. However, I have never used 'sum' in config-feedfoword or in the game code, so I'm wondering why this error is occurring.
And this is the code modified by GPT and config-feedforward.txt file:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zgzum4HR72b0eOUtvjY7tlB3v8xk0_O5?usp=drive_link
To solve the problem, I checked for any code containing sum, and following GPT's advice that the activation_default item was the issue, I changed it from activation_default = relu to sigmoid, but the 'sum' error still appears. The truly frustrating part is that I haven't used the word sum at all. Please help this suffering young developer.

Instead of sum you can use sigmoid, relu or something different and brute force your way into it, kindly check the official documentation of NEAT
